# Copy and paste as answer

Tags: discussion

For this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3722814/limit-question-and-existence) I am wondering if it would be wrong for me to copy and paste the comment into the answer box because being honest it answers my question. Let me know what I should do?

Comment: In the first instance you might wait a day or two to give the owner of the comment chance to see your request for them to add their own answer.

Comment: That's worth an answer, @PeterPhipps.  +1

Comment: @amWhy is that waiting too long is not worth it.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky Are you saying waiting a day or too is not worth it?  You got your answer already.  Why the need for you to copy and paste it to an answer field, and claim credit for it?

Comment: @amWhy Why does the question have to remain unanswered? when somebody commented on a question that is worth an answer I am not playing math politics, I write my answers in the answer box that simple. It helps reduce the unanswered question amount. Nobody mentioned claiming credit, you did.

Comment: The site is not going to come *crashing down* because a question is not answered within a day or two, @EnlightenedFunky.  And by copying and pasting another's answer into an answer post, you'd be claiming credit (and seeking rep for it).  Just because you didn't mention that fact doesn't mean that that's not what you'd, in effect, be doing.

Comment: You should not copy and paste someone else’s comment into an answer; even if you “give them credit”, even if you make it a CW answer so you don’t actually get reputation.  What you did, which is to post and encourage *them* to turn their comment into an answer, is the right step to take. 
If a sufficient length of time goes by with no action, you may consider composing your own answer to the question building on that person’s comment with suitable credit, but it would be best if you don’t just limit it to posting that person’s comment, but rather use it as a starting point to build an answer.

Comment: @amWhy I suggest you wary away from suggesting that would be claiming credit for it cause that is not the predicament here. So please I suggest you move away from hinting or even suggesting that I would claim credit for someone else's work probably you never learned in college about citations or references or Works Cited Pages or Bibliographies. Ever heard of libel, or slander.